# Optimizing Fibonacci in Elixir

Tags: elixir

```elixir
def firstFibonacciElements(n) do
    fib([1,1],n)
  end
  def fib(list,n) do
    list = list ++ [Enum.slice(list,-2..-1) |> Enum.sum]
    case length(list) < n do
      true -> fib(list,n)
      false -> list
    end
  end
```

I am trying to learn elixir, and wanted to understand if my code could be considered efficient, or why it isn't and what features of the language could help with that.

Answer (score 3):

You might use [Stream.unfold](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Stream.html#unfold/2).  Here your `n` is the `10`.

```
Stream.unfold({0,1}, fn {a,b} -> {a,{b,a+b}} end) |> Enum.take(10)
```

Here there are several features to understand:

- the use of an *anonymous* function `fn {a,b} -> {a,{b,a+b}} end` as the 2nd argument to the `unfold` function. The `fn` gets called repeatedly until sufficient data is generated.
- the use and transformation of tuples such as `{0,1}` and the *dummy* argument `{a,b}`
- the use of elixir's pipe notion `|>`
- the declaration of a Stream via `Stream.unfold` which must be resolved by piping it to a `Enum` function - most often  `Enum.to_list()` but here  `Enum.take(10)` which in our case takes the first ten items, then halts the Stream.

Answer (score 3):

Fibonacci could be written using the following recursive function:

```elixir
  def fib(n), do: fib(n, 1, 1)

  def fib(0, _a, _b), do: []

  def fib(n, a, b) when n > 0 do
    [a | fib(n - 1, b, a + b)]
  end
```

There are several performance pitfalls to avoid when working with [lists](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html), since these are linked lists and not arrays:

- when building a list incrementally, you should always prepend (`[elem | acc]`, constant time), never append (`acc ++ [elem]`, linear) - c.f. [erlang efficiency guide](https://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listhandling)
- `length/1` is linear, so you should avoid calling it on the accumulator and track the count yourself (in this case, just decrease `n` every step)
- accessing negative indexes (`Enum.slice/3`, `Enum.at/2`...) is also linear